# javascript - Don't allow multiple identical characters in a row

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I'm not too familiar with regex.  I have  `<textarea id='area'>` and want to allow only numbers or commas to be inputted. this works great

```
area.value=area.value.replace(/[^0-9,]/g,'');
```

It instantly deletes anything except commas and numbers.  I would also like to prevent multiple commas from being entered in a row. For example, if you entered or pasted 1,,2,,,3 into the textarea, it would change it to 1,2,3.  What could I add to the regex to make that work.
Thank you.

Comment: If you don't mind two replace statements you could add `.replace(/,+/g, ",")`... doing it with one expression is a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
area.value=area.value.replace(/[^0-9,]/g,'');
area.value= area.value.replace(/,+/g,',');
```

`,+` means consecutive commas together `like ,, or ,,,`

Comment: NB: it's generally not a good idea to make consecutive read/modify/write cycles to a DOM property.  It would be better to do one read (to a local variable), two modifies, and then one write.  The alternative would be `area.value = area.value.replace(...).replace(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative with a single replace statement:

```
"1,,2,,a,3,4".replace(/[^\d,]|,(?=\D*,)/g, "")
```

How it works:

`[^\d,]` is the same as `[0-9,]` then we also match any comma followed by zero or more nondigits (`\D`) and a comma. The `(?=` begins a positive look ahead group.